# <?php and <?= are not giving the same results

Tags: php

newbie here. I have been following a PHP course and I am having a bit of a problem with an annoying issue.

Everywhere I look, " <?= " is explained as the shorter version of " <?php " and they are the same. But when I try to pass data to URL using the code

```
<a href = "article.php?id=<?php $article["id"]; ?>">
```

I get http://localhost/article.php?id=

But when I use

```
<a href = "article.php?id=<?= $article["id"]; ?>">
```

I get http://localhost/article.php?id=1 , which is what I should be getting. Does anyone have an explanation about this? Should I be using " <?= " ?

Comment: `<?= $article["id"] ?>` is short for `<?php echo $article["id"]; ?>`. You have to *echo* the variable you want to be displayed.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot now. Thanks for the answer man!!

Comment: If there are resources telling you that `<?php` and `<?=` are the same, you should stop using those resources.